# 2nd order ODE to 1st order ODE/Forward euler method

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

I have a $2^\text{nd}$ ODE:

$$
\begin{cases}{d^2u \over dt^2} =5tu+\sin \left({du\over dt}\right)\\[5 pt] u(0)=1\\[5 pt] 
{du\over dt}(0)=0
\end{cases}
$$

I was reading my notes and it asked to write the $2^\text{nd}$ order ODE as a system of $1^\text{st}$ order ODEs. And then to construct a forward euler discretisation of the ODE with step size $\tau =1/2$ and interval $[0,2]$.

What was done in the notes was:

$$\begin{align}
\text{Let }&v={du \over dt}\\
&{dv \over dt}={d^2u \over dt^2}\\ 
\implies &{dv \over dt}=5tu+\sin v, \ v(0)=0.
\end{align}
$$

I understood the above, but I'm not sure what was done after that. Could someone explain to me what was done below? Let

$$
w= \left(
    \begin{matrix}
      u \\
      v
    \end{matrix}
  \right)\\ 
\text{then } {dw \over dt}=f(t,w), \;\;\;\;\;\; w(0)=w_0 \\
\text{where } f(t,w)=\left(
    \begin{matrix}
      v \\
      5tu+\sin v
    \end{matrix}
  \right) \text{ and } w_0=\left(
    \begin{matrix}
      1 \\
      0
    \end{matrix}
  \right)$$

---

Continuing on from there, how does the following work? In particular how does

$$
f(t_0, W^0)= \left(
    \begin{matrix}
      V^0 \\
      5\cdot 0 \cdot U^0 + \sin V^0 
    \end{matrix}
  \right) = \left(
    \begin{matrix}
      0 \\
      0
    \end{matrix}
  \right)$$

Forward euler for the $1^\text{st}$ order system: Given $W^0=w_0$, find $W^{n+1}$ such that $$W^{n+1}=W^n+\tau f(t_n,w)$$

$$n=0 \implies $W^0= \left(
    \begin{array}{c}
      1 \\
      0
    \end{array}
  \right) \\f(t_0, W^0)= \left(
    \begin{array}{c}
      V^0 \\
      5\cdot 0 \cdot U^0 + \sin V^0 
    \end{array}
  \right) = \left(
    \begin{array}{c}
      0 \\
      0
    \end{array}
  \right) \\ \implies W^1 = W^0 +\tau \left(
    \begin{array}{c}
      0 \\
      0
    \end{array}
  \right) \implies W^1 = W^0
$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$w$ as defined is a $2$-dimensional vector of functions, the first component of which is the function $u$ and the second component of which is the function $v=\frac{du}{dt}$.  When we differentiate, we differentiate componentwise:
$$
\frac{dw}{dt}=\begin{bmatrix}\tfrac{du}{dt} \\ \tfrac{dv}{dt}\end{bmatrix}.
$$
However, we know both $\frac{du}{dt}$ and $\frac{dv}{dt}$ (you said you understood this part).  Just plugging these in, we have that
$$
\frac{dw}{dt}=\begin{bmatrix}v \\ 5tu+\sin (v)\end{bmatrix}.
$$
Same thing with the initial condition:
$$
w(0)=\begin{bmatrix}u(0) \\ v(0)\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 0\end{bmatrix}.
$$

As for the numerical part, it seems that you should adust your equation $W^{n+1}=W^n+\tau f(t_n,w)$ to read
$$
W^{n+1}=W^n+\tau f(t_n,W^n).
$$
In any case, when you actually started to work out the problem, it seems as if this is what you did.  (Also keep in mind that $t_{n+1}=t_n+\tau$).

Comment: Thanks @JohnathanGleason , I understood everything you did. I just have one more question -- How do I get from 
$f(t_0, W^0)= \left(
    \begin{array}{c}
      V^0 \\
      5\cdot 0 \cdot U^0 + \sin V^0 
    \end{array}
  \right) = \left(
    \begin{array}{c}
      0 \\
      0
    \end{array}
  \right) $? In particular, shouldnt $U^0 =1$?

Comment: Yes, $U^0=u(0)=1$ and $V^0=u(0)=u'(0)=0$.

Comment: Thanks, understood it. Much appreciated again.